# Keyboard shortcut to switch focus between the two split windows of the same app in full-screen

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, window-manager, catalina, split-view

What is the keyboard shortcut to switch focus between the split windows of the same app (*not* between all the windows, only the 2 split ones)?

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↹</kbd> works only if you switch back from one split window to another, but if you visit some other window, e.g. window on another desktop, then it will not switch between the split windows, but between the currently used and previously used window.

The native keyboard shortcut for moving to the next window in focus, that can be activated in settings, also doesn’t work if you want to switch *between* the split windows **only**.